# Access Denied upload to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I tried uploading to s3 and when I see the logs from the s3 bucket logs this is what it says:

```
mybucket-me [17/Oct/2013:08:18:57 +0000] 120.28.112.39 
arn:aws:sts::778671367984:federated-user/dean@player.com BB3AA9C408C0D26F 
REST.POST.BUCKET avatars/dean%2540player.com/4.png "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 
AccessDenied 231 - 132 - "http://localhost:8080/ajaxupload/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17" -
```

I got an access denied. From where it's pointing I think the only thing that I'm missing out is adding of bucket policy. So here goes.

Using my email I could log in to my app and upload an avatar. The bucket name where I want to put my avatar is mybucket-me and in that it has a sub bucket named avatars.

```
-mybucket-me
 -avatars
  -dean@player.com //dynamic based on who are logged in
   -myavatar.png //image uploaded
```

**How do I add a bucket policy so I could grant a federated such as I to upload in s3** or what is the correct statement that I will add on my bucket policy so it could grant me a permission to upload into our bucket?

Answer (score 25):

### 2019+

You now either have to:

- Set **Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects** to **false** *if your items are public* (top left policie in the picture)

[image]

- Set `acl: 'private'` when uploading your image *if your items are private*

Example in Node.js:

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'moodboard-img',
        acl: 'private',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString())
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue and changing acl to private worked for me. Thanks :D

Comment: Wasted three hours, it's 1 AM but finally. I was using S3 with CloudFront which is why everything is private and it was causing error in uploading a file with Public access.

Answer (score 11):

To upload to S3 bucket, you need to Add/Create IAM/Group Policy, for example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `arn:aws:s3:::test` is your Amazon Resource Name (ARN).

Source: [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Related:

- [Specifying Resources in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html)
- [How to provide a user to access only a particular bucket in AWS S3?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/1626/3)

Comment: I don't think "DeleteObject" is specifically required for most uploads https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property but otherwise this is the most restrictive permissions to get this to work, I think

Answer (score 7):

You can attach the following policy to the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1358656005371",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1354655992561",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:sts::778671367984:federated-user/dean@player.com"                  
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

to grant the federated user dean@player.com read-only permissions to 'my.bucket'.

This policy is not very maintainable because it names this user in particular. To give access to only certain federated users in a more scalable way, it would be better to do this when you call GetFederationToken. If you post your STS code I can help you assigning the policy there, but it is very similar to the above.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late response. Im using the s3 browser upload, we have an API that we call which give us the credentials. Here is a link where almost all of the relevant code are posted. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401936/signaturedoesnotmatch-browser-based-upload-to-s3?noredirect=1#comment28781719_19401936)

Comment: Will this be okay actions are only "List & Get"? What im trying to do is an upload or post method. Also your correct what I need is the scalable way, different user will be uploading on the bucket. Please help.

Comment: You need to change the actions to whatever you need, just "s3:*" will give you access to all S3 actions.

What language are you using? Post the code you have so far

Comment: Hi prestomation, im using javascript+jquery Ajax. Here is a link to all my related source code. Please [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401936/signaturedoesnotmatch-browser-based-upload-to-s3?noredirect=1#comment28781719_19401936)

Comment: Please notice that s3:* access will also give you DeleteBucket permission. Limiting that action to specific key within a bucket should prevent actual bucket deletion, but that is still a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using programmatic access using credential or aws-sdk with any server then try to comment ACL:public-read then everything works fine without any changes if IAM has already permission to (crud) itself

enjoy ! no more google